# Трансформируется img в flex блоке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

[image: Все испортилось когда я добавил кнопку которую я обвел]

Flexbox  растягивает изображение до конца блока .
Когда кнопки нет все отлично,потому что так изображение длиннее чем текстовый блок. 
Все решается если не давать изображению трансформироваться. Увы я такого свойства не знаю.-не доучил

```
<div class="container ourTeam">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>our team<span>.</span></h1>
                <p>They are big but still friendly.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/png/Joey.png" alt="">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h3>joey</h3>
                        <h5>web developer</h5>
                        <p>Coffee lover.  Always on bike. iPhone fan.</p>
                        <a href="#">more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/png/Matt.png" alt="">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h3>Matt</h3>
                        <h5>web designer</h5>
                        <p>MTB Biker. Photoshop Master. Loving Father.</p>
                        <a href="#">more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/png/Mike.png" alt="">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h3>Mike</h3>
                        <h5>copywriter</h5>
                        <p>Drummer. Soup lover. Beer Drinker. Cyclist.</p>
                        <a href="#">more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
.ourTeam {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}
.ourTeam h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #314a5b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.ourTeam h1 span {
  color: #fa5c65;
}
.ourTeam p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #9aa0ab;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.ourTeam .items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.ourTeam .item {
  display: flex;
}
.ourTeam .item h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #314a5b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.ourTeam .item h5 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fa5c65;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.ourTeam .item p {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #9aa0ab;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.ourTeam .item a {
  color: #fa5c65;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: оберните img в блок

Comment: Вот это  я затупил